# matlab pathfinder - problems with understanding

Tags: matlab, path

I got an matlab-function which shall find files by returning their path. This is exactly what i need for my purpose. The problem is that the code is written by me. So I do not quite understand how this function works, especially the inputs which I do not understand.

I hope u can help me to understand this function.
Best regards!

Here is the code:

```
function B = getAllPaths(basepath, name)
temp=genpath(basepath);
A=regexp(temp,';','split');
j=1;
for i=1:length(A)-1
pfad=cell2mat(A(i));
if(exist([pfad name],'file'))
B(j)=cellstr(pfad);
j=j+1;
end
end
clear A i name pfad temp
```

Comment: Upvote for _The problem is that the code is written by me_

Answer (score 0):

I would write that function as

```
%// Get all child directories of 'basepath' that contain a file named 'name'
function B = getAllPaths(basepath, name)
    A = regexp(genpath(basepath), ';', 'split');
    B = A(cellfun(@(x) exist([x name],'file') ~= 0, A));
end
```

or

```
%// Get all child directories of 'basepath' that contain a file named 'name'
function B = getAllPaths(basepath, name)
    if ispc
        [OK,dirs] = system(['cd "' basepath '" && dir /s /b "' name '"']);
    elseif isunix
        [OK,dirs] = system(['find "' basepath '" -type f -name "' name '"']);
    end
    if ~OK
        B = cellfun(@fileparts, cellstr(b), 'UniformOutput', false);
    else
        B = {};
    end
end
```

MATLAB is interactive! So interact with it! Use any typical `basepath` and `name` and execute your function in the command window, line by line, displaying the output each time. Try to change a few commands and see how that changes the output. Type `help cellfun` and *Read, Learn, Master*. Click on links in `see also [...]` at the bottom of each `help`, even though you think you know it. Type `edit cell2mat` and *Read, Learn, Master*, etc. etc. etc.

Understanding a language takes practice, not a bunch of answers from some forum.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your advice. I know it takes time to learn how to program. Im still examining this code but I have not understand it yet completely.

I got a problem with the line:
exist([pfad name],'file')

E.g. When I try to find "xyz" a file in folder "ABC" what must be in "name"? I write "ABC" in name but then it does net work.

Kind regards!